# How to fit JQuery datatable to entire screen width irrespective of the screen resolution?

Tags: html, css, datatables

I am using JQuery Datatable in my Rails application as shown below:

```rb
<%= content_tag :table, 
                role: :my_datatable, 
                id: 'my_datatable', 
                style: 'height:500px; overflow-y: auto;',
                class: 'table table-responsive reconciletable  table-striped table-bordered table-hover', 
                data: { url: my_datatable_path(format: :json)} do %>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account Number</th>
      <th>Account Name</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th></th>      
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  </tbody>

<% end %>
```

When the screen resolution is high, the datatable covers only half the screen width and does not fit the entire width.

How do I make this fit the entire width please?

I tried these 2 approaches but neither worked (both involve adding a `width: 100%`):

**Approach 1:**

```rb
<%= content_tag :table, 
                role: :my_datatable, 
                id: 'my_datatable', 
                style: 'height:500px; overflow-y: auto;',
                width: '100%',
                class: 'table table-responsive reconciletable  table-striped table-bordered table-hover', 
                data: { url: my_datatable_path(format: :json)} do %>
```

**Approach 2:**

```rb
<%= content_tag :table, 
                role: :my_datatable, 
                id: 'my_datatable', 
                style: 'height:500px; width: 100%; overflow-y: auto;',
                class: 'table table-responsive reconciletable  table-striped table-bordered table-hover', 
                data: { url: my_datatable_path(format: :json)} do %>
```

Please help!

Comment: Your question has nothing todo with Rails nor the database but CSS.

Comment: Are you using any CSS frameworks like Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of Rahul's answer and Meet Dave's answer + 1 more change I tried worked. If I remove either of the 3 changes, then it does not work (well - the width would increase for each of the 3 fixes but still would not completely fill the screen width).

So, the combination of these 3 steps worked like a charm:

1. Meet Dave's Answer - change `100%` to `100vw`
2. Rahul's answer - remove `table-responsive`
3. Something I tried - remove `reconciletable`

So this worked (all 3 of the above implemented in this snippet)

```rb
    <%= content_tag :table, 
                role: :my_datatable, 
                id: 'my_datatable', 
                style: 'height:500px; width: 100vw; overflow-y: auto;',
                class: 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover', 
                data: { url: my_datatable_path(format: :json)} do %>
```

NOTE: `<div class="container-fluid">` did not really help with this.

Thanks much Rahul & Dave!!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `content_tag` inside a `div` with `container-fluid` `class` like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <%= content_tag :table,  role: :my_datatable,  id: 'my_datatable',  style: 
    'height:500px; overflow-y: auto;', width: '100%', class: 'table table-responsive 
    reconciletable  table-striped table-bordered table-hover',  data: { url: 
    my_datatable_path(format: :json)} do %>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this `<div id="datatable_div" class="container-fluid">` but that didn't seem to work though. Am I missing something else here?

Comment: @Biju try removing `table-responsive` class from `content_tag`

Answer (score 1):

Setting width to 100vw will cover the entire screen width irrespective of the resolution.

Further explanation: `width: 100vw;` is set relative to veiwport width. (this covers 100% of the viewport)
Where as `width: 100%` is set relative to parent div (this covers 100% of parent's width.

```
width: 100vw;
```